# Remove all similar elements in an array if count of element is less than 'n'

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array containing multiple thousands of elements, many which are duplicates of other elements. What I need is a way to find the count of 'foo' element in the array, and if less than 'n', remove all elements of 'foo' from the array.

Example of what I need

```
string[] words = new string[]
int n = 8;
int k = Occurances of "foo" in words;
if (k < n) {
    //Remove all occurances of 'foo' in the array
}
```

If the starting elements in the array 'words' were

```
{"foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar"}
```

The result would be the following left in the array, because only 7 occurances of "foo" were found, but 9 occurances of "bar" were found

```
{"bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar","bar"}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Hendry I've tried dumping the contents into a `Dictionary`, get the count of each element in the Dictionary, and then delete accordingly, but the conversions back and forth weren't working correctly, and was a general pain

Comment: Is the original order of the elements important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `LINQ` `GroupBy` and `Count` to achieve that:

```
string[] words = new string[] { "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar" };
int n = 8;
var groups = words.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() >= n);
```

What you do here is to group the elements by the element value (foo group and bar group) and you count each group, getting the group which has number of elements greater than certain threshold (n = 8 in your case)

To get the array back, you could simply progress a little more by using `SelectMany`:

```
string[] filteredWords = words.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() >= n)
    .SelectMany(g => g).ToArray();
```

Comment: This works nicely, but it leaves the results in the form of `IGrouping`. How do I convert this back to an array?

Comment: You can progress a little bit more by using `SelectMany`, I'll update my answer

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Now is it possible to expand this a little further, and check for occurances in parts of strings? For example, I may have "foo extrabits" and "bar extrabits", can I check for just the foo and bar of the string using your method?

Comment: in that case, you should have double process.. but this depends on how you want the `checking` to behave. For instance "occurrence of the string" could mean two different things: (1) "boa" occurs in "boasting" (2) "boa" does not occur in "boasting" but in "boa snake"

Comment: The second one works better for my case. There will be the word I'm checking for, then a space

Comment: In that case then you probably need to combine the concept above with string.Split(' ') - I haven't really tried it but there should be a nice way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

This works and it retains the original order of the elements.

```
var words = new[]
{
    "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
    "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar",
    "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar",
    "bar"
};

var keepers = new HashSet<string>(
    words.ToLookup(x => x).Where(x => x.Skip(7).Any()).Select(x => x.Key));

words = words.Where(w => keepers.Contains(w)).ToArray();
```

If order isn't important then this will do:

```
words =
    words
        .ToLookup(x => x)
        .Where(x => x.Skip(7).Any())
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToArray();
```

---

As per your comment, "Is it possible to expand this a little further, and check for occurances in parts of strings?", I assume that you mean that you want to count the individual frequencies of part of a "word" and keep the entire "word" if it meets the frequency requirement. That might not be much clearer. Here's my code:

```
var words = new[]
{
    "foo", "foo", "foo extrabits", "foo", "foo",
    "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar",
    "bar", "bar", "bar extrabits", "bar", "bar",
    "bar"
};

var keepers =
    new HashSet<string>(
        words
            .SelectMany(x => x.Split(' '))
            .ToLookup(x => x)
            .Where(x => x.Skip(7).Any())
            .Select(x => x.Key));

words =
    words
        .Where(x => x.Split(' ').Any(y => keepers.Contains(y)))
        .ToArray();
```

This produces:

```
bar 
bar 
bar 
bar 
bar 
bar extrabits 
bar 
bar 
bar
```

Comment: Is it possible to expand this a little further, and check for occurances in parts of strings? For example, I may have "foo extrabits" and "bar extrabits", can I check for just the foo and bar of the string using your method?

Comment: @CocoaMix86 - Yes, you could easily do it with a `.Split(' ')` and a `.SelectMany(...)` before the `.ToLookup(...)`.